# Trouble Parsing Long Style Arguments in Bash using getopt

Tags: bash, getopt

This script of mine does not seem to be recognizing any other option other than --norecopy and even that only when specified as second argument to my script.

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

norecopy=false
noencrypt=false
nopackage=false

# read the option
OPTS=`getopt --long norecopy,noencrypt,nopackage -n 'build' -- "$@"`

eval set -- "$OPTS"

while true ; do
    case "$1" in
        --norecopy ) echo "found norecopy" ; norecopy=true ; shift ;;
        --noencrypt ) echo "found noencrypt" ; noencrypt=true ; shift ;;
        --nopackage ) echo "found nopackage" ; nopackage=true ; shift ;;
        -- ) echo "Got here" ; shift ; break ;;
        * ) echo "unsupported option!" ; break ;;
    esac
done

exit 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code works!

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

norecopy=false
noencrypt=false
nopackage=false

# read the option
OPTS=`getopt --long norecopy,noencrypt,nopackage -n 'build' - "$@"`

eval set -- "$OPTS"

while true ; do
    case "$1" in
        --norecopy ) echo "found norecopy" ; norecopy=true ; shift ;;
        --noencrypt ) echo "found noencrypt" ; noencrypt=true ; shift ;;
        --nopackage ) echo "found nopackage" ; nopackage=true ; shift ;;
        -- ) echo "Got here" ; shift ; break ;;
        * ) echo "unsupported option!" ; break ;;
    esac
done

exit 0
```

I added 'set -x' to debug the issue. I saw that a single hyphen character (as opposed to two consecutive hyphen characters) in getopt command prints output as expected. See below two commands:

```
$ getopt --long norecopy,noencrypt,nopackage -n build -- --norecopy --noencrypt --nopackage
 --noencrypt --nopackage --

$ getopt --long norecopy,noencrypt,nopackage -n build - --norecopy --noencrypt --nopackage
 --norecopy --noencrypt --nopackage --
```

I still don't know the reason behind this behavior of getopt. Someone on the forum having getopt source code experience might be able to help. However this change should get you going!

Comment: Thanks a ton. What a mysterious fix!